# Multiple paths in encoded polyline

Tags: geolocation, maps, mapbox, geojson

I am trying to add several "LineStrings" or path lines to a map. I have tried using FeatureCollection and adding multiple features with different individual "LineStrings". But the problem I am having is that I am quickly reaching the size limit of a URL request.

I have tried using encoded polylines, but the problem is that I need to display the path lines as separate lines for each array of coordinates.

Is there a way to create an encoded polyline from several lat/long arrays and keeps each path seperate?

Comment: Do you need to represent the map as a static image? Only the static image API will have a length restriction: if you can use JavaScript, using Mapbox.js or Mapbox GL JS will let you add lots of lines to a map without issue.

Comment: Hi tmcw. I am trying to do this with a java client, so my approach was using the REST API. My next option will be to try using what I can from the Android SDK.